# MonetDB doesn't recognize function names given to mclient via command line

Tags: bash, monetdb

I am trying to export a few columns from a table as encoded integer.
Basically I want to use a bash script to pass the SQL command to `mclient` as command line argument. My bash script looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash

dir=`pwd`

for col in occupation native_country martial_status race sex
do
    mclient -d adult -s \
        "create function encode${col}(s varchar(200)) returns int begin return (select code from ${col}_dict where ${col}=s); end;"
    mclient -d adult -s \
        "COPY (select encode${col}($col) from adult) INTO '${dir}/${col}.txt' NULL AS '0'"
    mclient -d adult -s \
       "drop function encode${col}"
done
```

In each iteration, I want to create a SQL function on the fly. Then use the function to encode an attribute and export it to a text file. And lastly drop the function.

However, the output strangely contains some monster characters,
as if it can't recognize the function name.
If I remove the second `mclient` command, the other operations are successful.

```
operation successful
Function 'X�..X�' not defined
operation successful
operation successful
Function '��"X�.X�' not defined
operation successful
operation successful
Function ' X�.PX�' not defined
```

Comment: This works fine for me. Could you please add more details, at least the MonetDB version, OS version, the schema of the `adult` database?

Comment: @HannesMühleisen I am using `MonetDB Database Server v1.7 (Jan2014-SP2)` and `Ubuntu 14.04 LTS`. The adult dataset is from http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Adult . I myself did some preprocessing and built some dictionary in the database, which would be too wordy to explain here. I suspect, if it can be because of the character encoding issue (say, ASCII or UTF-8, but I never change any setting myself) between MonetDB and shell command line?